# PHP - clean text from all html, css and JS code

Tags: php, code-cleanup

I need to clean some text from all HTML, CSS and JS code.

I am using this function, but sometimes, there are some inline codes there.

Do you have a better function than the one I am using?

Here is my code:

```
function cleanContent($str){
    $str = str_replace(array("  "), " ",str_replace(array("   "), "", $str));

    $pattern3 = "/\..*?{.*}/";
    $str = preg_replace($pattern3,"",$str);

    $pattern1 = "/#.*?{.*?}/";
    $str = preg_replace($pattern1,"",$str);

    $pattern2 = "/.:.*?{.*?}/";
    $str = preg_replace($pattern2,"",$str);

    $pattern4 = "/(body|ul|li|a|img|tr|td|html)\s{.*?}/";
    $str = preg_replace($pattern4,"",$str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using strip_tags - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php?

Answer (score 3):

To clean from HTML you should use strip_tags();

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

second parameter is array with allowable tags. It is no sense in writing your own funciton.

This function will remove also css and js which is included into  and  tags.

Comment: Well this functions will work only if there is really good made tags. But in my case the tags are not availible. What to do then?